# How do you format time into timezones in python?

Tags: python

How do you get time to be formatted like this in python?

```
2020-12-18T21:43:42Z
```

What I have tried so far:

```
from datetime import date
date.fromisoformat('2020-12-18T21:43:42Z')
```

Comment: Are you trying to go *to* a string, or *from* a string?

Comment: i wanna this format 2020-12-18T21:43:42Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you shared isn't the iso format that `datetime` uses, but you could explicitly format the datetime yourself using `strftime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
result = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```